# Apache thrift, struct contain itself

Tags: protocol-buffers, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am looking into thrift for serialization of data. But Document says

**cyclic structs - Structs can only contain structs that have been declared before it. A struct also cannot contain itself**

One of our requirement is

- Struct A

  - List of Child items

    - Items(Items are Struct A )

So reading requirement i can't have Struct within itself at any level? can i have it in cyclic model as i have it above. Struct is not member of Struct directly but it has some other member and it contains struct.

Their document is not so well descriptive.

**Is it possible in Thrift? Does protobuf supports it?**

Answer (score 2):

According to [this discussion](http://markmail.org/message/57zdq7l4jkschkxn#query:apache%20thrift%20recursive+page:1+mid:57zdq7l4jkschkxn+state:results), it's not possible in Thrift.  However, there is a workaround of using integers to index into a master list.  Essentially, this is a form of poor man's pointers.

```
struct A 
{ 
1: list<i32> subitems; 
}

struct AllAs 
{ 
1: list<A> items; 
}
```

subitems is essentially a list of pointers into AllAs.items

In Protocol Buffers, it's trivial:

```
message A {
    repeated A subitems = 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **starting with Thrift 0.9.2 this scenario is supported**.

With any earlier version of thrift the following (intentionally) lead to an compiler error message:

```
struct Foo {
  1 : Foo foo     // error - Foo not fully defined yet
  2 : Bar bar     // error - Bar not defined yet
}

struct Bar {
  1 : Foo left     // ok, Foo has been defined earlier
  2 : Foo right    // ok, Foo has been defined earlier
}
```

There are still a few caveats though. The deveoper is responsible for not producing endless loops or diamond references, like

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.foo = foo;    // will crash on serialization with stack overflow

var bar = new Bar();
bar.left = foo;
bar.right = foo;   // points to same object only BEFORE deserialization
```